# Android best practices to avoid memoryleaks?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I am developing an application in android and experienced a memory leak with an anonymous class, are there best practices or common scenarios to avoid memoryleaks in android?

Comment: The main memory leak source in android is context leaking. This http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html is a good start.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a design pattern that helps you with memory leaks, since you could manage incorrectly resources in any design pattern you use to architecture your app, I would think more on "Best Practices" instead of "Design Patterns", as best practices there's plently of things you must take on count when implementing any code, like:

- Nullify Objects when done using them
- Make use of WeakReferences when possible
- Close Input/Output streams
- Release no longer needed resources
- Recycle bitmaps.
- Avoid object creation in "Loops or repetitive functions" if possible

Hope this list of "Best Practices" help...

Regards!

Comment: Half those things on this list will not by themselves cause memory leaks.  For example, nulling objects is not required.

Comment: nullifying can be misleading. A method-local reference is destroyed after the method ends anyway, and nullifying one reference does not make the object available for GC if you passed it somewhere where a ref is kept.

Comment: Both have correct correct comments, however @Simon keeping reference to objects that might be no longer needed will prevent the GC from destroying it, it's not an important memory leak, but definitely a poor memory managment...

Comment: A leak is not holding on to something you no longer need.  That just uses more memory than you need to and is bad practice.  A leak is when you create an object which cannot be reached by the GC, especially when it's done repetitively.  For example, holding a static reference to an Activity context, e.g. in the Application singleton.  When the activity is destroyed, it cannot, ever, be GCed because there is a static reference with a life time equal to the application.  Also, remember that nulling an object only nuills the reference.  It does NOT free it if there is another reference somewhere.